# Adding geometry.type circle?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry

I have to amend the following code so that on the map it's possible to draw a second circle graphic as well as a line, polygon and point. I've tried to add an else if statement much like the polygon type but that hasn't worked.

Can anyone advise?

```
function addSearchGraphic(geometry) {

    drawToolbar.deactivate();
    map.enableMapNavigation();
    var type = geometry.type; //can only ever be a point or polygon

    if (type === "point") {
        $('#point').button("option", "label", "Draw Another Search Point");
        $('#polygon').button("disable");
        $('#line').button("disable");
        $('#circle').button("disable");
        symbol = drawToolbar.markerSymbol;
        searchgraphicsLayer.add(new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol));
    } else if (type === "polygon") {
        $('#point').button("disable");
        $('#line').button("disable");
        symbol = drawToolbar.fillSymbol;
        if (esri.geometry.polygonSelfIntersecting(geometry)) {
            alert('Problem! The area you have drawn has a boundary that crosses over itself.  Please redraw your area');
        } else {
            $('#polygon').button("option", "label", "Draw Another Search Area");
            searchgraphicsLayer.add(new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol));
        }   
    } else if (type === "polyline") {
        $('#line').button("option", "label", "Draw Another Search Line");
        $('#point').button("disable");
        $('#polygon').button("disable");
        $('#circle').button("disable");
        symbol = drawToolbar.lineSymbol;
        searchgraphicsLayer.add(new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol));
    }
    bufferSearchGeometries();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have symbols set up for all those options (you probably do too). Something like this ...

```
 symbols = {};
 symbols.circle = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([0, 0, 180, 0.25]));
```

or in your "else if" block,

```
} else if (type === "circle") {
  symbols.arrow = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([0, 0, 180, 0.25]));
```

All of the second part (with the else if) is inside a function activateTool(type) as in this sample ... [drawing tools](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html). That sample is what I drew upon (no pun intended) for my drawing tools map and the "type" that is activated is indicated by the button that is clicked.

Another piece of this that I borrowed from a different sample (but it serves the same purpose as the "registry.forEach" line in the sample is like this ...

```
  // find the divs for buttons
  query(".drawing").forEach(function(btn) {
    var button = new Button({
      label: btn.innerHTML,
      onClick: function() {
        activateTool(this.id);
      }
    }, btn);
  });
```

And that serves to automate the creation of the buttons using dojo. It requires that I have these divs and it adds the buttons to the divs automagically.

```
  <div id="drawingWrapper">
    Draw Stuff!:
    <div id="point" class="drawing">Point</div>
    <div id="freehandpolyline" class="drawing">Freehand Polyline</div>
    <div id="freehandpolygon" class="drawing">Freehand Polygon</div>
    <div id="line" class="drawing">Straight Line</div>
    <div id="circle" class="drawing">Circle</div>
    <div id="arrow" class="drawing">Arrow</div>
  </div>
```

If you get stuck take a look at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jbchurchill/r7d1dw6t/4/) that I made.